# Exact integral gives different result from numerical integral

Tags: numerical-integration

Can anybody help me to make sense of this? Integrate yields one value, which is numerically different from the result given by NIntegrate.

```
Clear[v]; j = 2; x = -1; n = 2;   {x1 = ((I*(2*Pi*I)^(j - 1))/2)*Integrate[(1 - Coth[Pi*v])*(E^(x*(n + 1 + I*v))*(n + 1 + I*v)^(j - 1) - E^(x*(n + 1 - I*v))*(n + 1 - I*v)^(j - 1)), {v, 0, Infinity}], N[x1, 5], ((I*(2*Pi*I)^(j - 1))/2)*NIntegrate[(1 - Coth[Pi*v])*(E^(x*(n + 1 + I*v))*(n + 1 + I*v)^(j - 1) - E^(x*(n + 1 - I*v))*(n + 1 - I*v)^(j - 1)), {v, 0, Infinity}]}
```

For a better visuals, here's what's going on:

[image]

The value given by NIntegrate is numerically equal to $\frac{i(11-18 e+5 e^2)\pi}{(e-1)^2 e^3}$ (obtained analytically), so NIntegrate should be right, but not Integrate.

Comment: All right in 13.1 on Windows 19., where `{-((I \[Pi] (-16 + 6 Coth[1/2] + Csch[1/2]^2))/(
  2 E^3)), -0.052117 I, -8.86827*10^-21 - 0.0521172 I}` is produced.

Comment: And me 13.0.1.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: Mathematica v12.2 gives `{0. - 0.0521172 I, 0. - 0.0521172 I, -1.66526*10^-21 - 0.0521172 I}` which seems to be numerically equal!

Comment: That's crazy, but when it comes to inaccuracies on Mathe I am no longer surprised. Haha

Comment: Which version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: As I said, 13.0.1.0 on windows 10.